# Age Reverse Calculation Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate age from Day,Month and Year.I already done Date Of Birth to Day,Month,Year calculation.But I want age reverse calculation

If user enter Age of : 
Day:18
Month:05
Year:26

Then It will return the Original Date of Birth from current date Like DOB:10/24/1993

There are lot of example of DOB to Age(dd-mm-yyyy) but no example of Age(dd-mm-yyyy) to DOB

[image]

What is the logic of this reverse calculation in javascript?

here is the script for DOB to Age

```
$("#txtDob").keyup(function () {
                debugger;
                var mdate = $("#txtDob").val().toString();
                var yearThen = parseInt(mdate.substring(0, 4), 10);
                var monthThen = parseInt(mdate.substring(5, 7), 10);
                var dayThen = parseInt(mdate.substring(8, 10), 10);

                var today = new Date();
                var birthday = new Date(yearThen, monthThen - 1, dayThen);

                var differenceInMilisecond = today.valueOf() - birthday.valueOf();

                var year_age = Math.floor(differenceInMilisecond / 31536000000);
                var day_age = Math.floor((differenceInMilisecond % 31536000000) / 86400000);

                var month_age = Math.floor(day_age / 30);

                day_age = day_age % 30;

                if (isNaN(year_age) || isNaN(month_age) || isNaN(day_age)) {
                    // $("#exact_age").text("Invalid birthday - Please try again!");
                }
                else {
                    $("#txtAgeYY").val(year_age);
                    $("#txtAgeMM").val(month_age);
                    $("#txtAgeDD").val(day_age);
                    //var abc = testFunc();
                }
            });
```

but I need Age to DOB

Comment: Show your script, pls

Comment: it's hard to answer without script shown..

Comment: I added the script for DOB to Age,but I want Age to DOB from current date.You guys please tell me the logic.

Comment: The script seems to calculate age of user in days, months and years. txtAgeYY, txtAgeMM and txtAgeDD are not intended to input date of birth separately. And second - it treats `#txtDob` like RTL input. I'd like to say that you even didn't try to test the code chunk you posted

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new date that holds the current time and then subtract the current age year, month and day.

```
const ageYear = 26;
const ageMonth = 5;
const ageDay = 18;

const birthDay = new Date();

birthDay.setFullYear(birthDay.getFullYear() - ageYear);
birthDay.setMonth(birthDay.getMonth() - ageMonth);
birthDay.setDate(birthDay.getDate() - ageDay);
```

Comment: But its returning wrong DOB,I think leap year is not calculate properly

Comment: Your example of computing the age does not compute the age correctly. You should not use milliseconds difference and then divide by `31536000000`. The years have different number of milliseconds in them, as you said the leap year.

Comment: Try to compute the age at the exact moment a person turns 26 and was born in 10/24/1993. He turn 26 on 10/24/2019 right? Your algorithm gives 26 years and 6 days.
 


`
const current = new Date(2019, 10, 24);
const birth = new Date(1993, 10, 24);

const diff = current.valueOf() - birth.valueOf();

const year_age = Math.floor(diff / 31536000000);
const day_age = Math.floor((diff % 31536000000) / 86400000);

console.log(year_age, day_age)
`

Comment: I tried your code and it showing 10/16/1993,it should be 10/24/1993.can you edit your code once properly,please.

Comment: Today we are in `4/3/2020` and the age is 26 years, 5 months, 18 days. 
Subtract 18 days from now => 3/16/2020
Subtract 5 months => 10/16/2019
Subtract 26 years => 10/16/1993 and not 10/24/1993. Your algorithm for computing the date from BOD is wrong.

Comment: You guys are correct,actually my DOB to Age logic in incorrect.Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Check below javascript part will do what you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
   var ageYears = 26;
   var ageMonths = 5;
   var ageDays = 18;
   var today = new Date();
   var year = today.getFullYear();
   var month = today.getMonth();
   var day = today.getDate();
   var dob = new Date(year - ageYears, month - ageMonths, day - ageDays);
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "DOB: " + dob;
 </script>

</body>
```

Comment: It also returning Sat Oct 16 1993 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),Instead of Sat Oct 24 1993 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) :(

Comment: You guys are correct,actually my DOB to Age logic is incorrect.Thanks :)

Comment: @Vidhya Please check whether your age calculation is correct based on DOB. I get 26 years 5 months and 9 days.